# How to get last button selected in button group?

Tags: arrays, swift, uibutton

In this code, when i select a button it reveals the image behind the "question-mark". If i select another button, the first image is reset back to the default question mark image and the other button's image is revealed.

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    
    self.buttonGroup.forEach { (button) in
                //Reset button to default state
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "question-mark"), for: .normal)
        
        
        }
    
    //image of card selected
    let cardSelected = buttonGroup[sender.tag].currentBackgroundImage
    
    sender.setBackgroundImage(cardSelected, for: .normal)
```

Now, I am trying to compare the two images(1st and 2nd clicks) to see if they are a match, but I am struggling with getting the value for the previous button's click. (I already have a working function that compares the images, so I just need to figure out how to get the value of the last clicked image.

I tried this but i created my buttons programmatically so I'm not sure where to declare "firstButton" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812494/multiple-buttons-to-single-ibaction-how-to-change-background-of-the-previous-t)

Please share any advice if you have some :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store previous button tag like :

```
var prevTag : Int = -1
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
     if  buttonGroup[prevTag].currentBackgroundImage == 
          buttonGroup[sender.tag].currentBackgroundImage{
      // matches 
     }

      self.buttonGroup.forEach { (button) in
            //Reset button to default state
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "question-mark"), for: .normal)

    }
  
     let cardSelected = buttonGroup[sender.tag].currentBackgroundImage

     sender.setBackgroundImage(cardSelected, for: .normal)
     prevTag = sender.tag
```

Comment: Hello thank you but I'm getting an index out of range error when I click a button because of prevTag??

Comment: Nvm i put an if-statement around it to make sure it was >= 0 thanks!!